# XMLRPC Not working on Localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, xml-rpc

Hey guys, I've been working on a Wordpress theme for a while now and all works fine when it's on my server, but when I load it up on my machine locally I am unable to utilise certain functionality, namely the ability to post from outside the admin panel. To do this I use XMLRPC and the following code -

```
$params = array(0,$username,$password,$content,true);
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request('metaWeblog.newPost',$params);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rpcurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
$results = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

The params passed are all valid and correct, and I just cannot figure out what is wrong for the life of me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your fail point... sounds like your local machine isn't completely setup.  Presumably PHP works if it gets to `xmlrpc_encode_request` before failing, but is `php.ini` setup correctly, and the `XML-RPC` library enabled?

Update:
You need to remove the semi-colon from the line:

```
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
```

Comment: How would I go about altering that? I set up a PHP info file and couldn't find 'XML-RPX' anywhere.

Comment: Tom! Sorry, typo... `XML-RPC` library (fixed) + added the extension line from your `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried seeing what the response from the $results variable is? Is the $rpcurl variable set to the right URL?

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response, but the page appears to die after xmlrpc_encode_request() is called, therefore I am unable to view the contents of that variable.